# Partial View's checkbox state not returned to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a main view whose Model is of type FacilityViewModel. The main view loads a partial view that also contains a partial view. Both partial views have a model of type FiltersViewModel. The most nested partial view loops through a dictionary and creates a checkbox for each item to allow users to select which facility they want to filter their data by. However, once control returns to my controller action, the items selected in the _FacilityFilterPartialView are not set to true. Every value in the dictionary is still set to false. I'm doing this same thing elsewhere in the application with a little different viewmodel structure and it works fine. But for some reason this isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

ViewModels:

```
public class FiltersViewModel 
{
    public Dictionary<string, bool> FacilityList { get; set; }
}

public class FacilityViewModel
{
    public FiltersViewModel Filters { get; set; }

}
```

_FacilityFilterPartialView:

```
@model MyApp.ViewModel.FiltersViewModel

@foreach (var key in Model.FacilityList.Keys)
{           
    <label style="white-space:nowrap">                   
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(r => r.FacilityList [key], new { @class = "fChkbox" })
        @Html.DisplayFor(r => key, new { @style = "nowrap" })
    </label>
}
</div>
```

_FiltersPartialView.cshtml:

```
@model MyApp.ViewModel.FiltersViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Partial("_FacilityFilterPartialView", @Model)
    ...
}
```

Main View Index.cshtml:

```
@model MyApp.ViewModel.FacilityViewModel
<div>
    @Html.Partial("_FiltersPartialView", Model.Filters)
</div>
```

Controller Code:

viewModel is of type FacilityViewModel

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection fc)
{       
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      TryUpdateModel(viewModel);
      //State of checkboxes is not correct at this point.
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

asp.net MVC model binding can only bind to one model. To solve your issue you would simply need to create a base class that all your models, that may use a FacilityList , would derive from.

Like so:

```
public class FacilityViewModel 
{
    public Dictionary<string, bool> FacilityList { get; set; }
}
```

then your FiltersViewModle would look like so

```
public class FiltersViewModel : FacilityViewModel
{
    public FiltersViewModel Filters { get; set; }
}
```

Once that is in place you would need to change the parameters of your controller to take a FiltersViewModel

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FiltersViewModel viewModel)
{       
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      var test = viewModel.FacilityList;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you controls names do not match your model. Your generating html for the check boxes with `name="FacilityList[xxxx]"` (where `xxxx` is the dictionary key) but `FacilityViewModel` does not have a property named `FacilityList` - only a property named `Filters` (which in turn contains a property named `FacilityList`)

In order to bind to `FacilityViewModel` the name attribute of the checkboxes would need to be `name="Filters.FacilityList[xxxx]"`

If you only need `FiltersViewModel` in the POST method, then the signature should be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FiltersViewModel model)
```

Alternatively if you need `FacilityViewModel` (assuming it contains other properties you have not shown), then you need to ensure the `name` attributes have the correct prefix which can be done by using

```
@Html.Partial("_FiltersPartialView", Model.Filters, new ViewDataDictionary { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "Filters" }})
```

and the POST method signature should be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FacilityViewModel model)
```

Side note: Bind to your models, not `FormCollection`